# Why is (rf)clf feature_importance giving importance to a feature where all values are the same?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, feature-selection

I am comparing multi-classification with Random Forests and CART in scikit-learn.

Two of my features (feature 4 and feature 6) are irrelevant for the classification because all the values are the same.
But output of the feature_importances of the RandomForestClassifier is the following:

> Feature ranking:
>
> 1. feature 3 (0.437165)
> 2. feature 2 (0.216415)
> 3. **feature 6 (0.102238)**
> 4. feature 5 (0.084897)
> 5. feature 1 (0.064624)
> 6. **feature 4 (0.059332)**
> 7. feature 0 (0.035328)

CART feature_importance output:

> Feature ranking:
>
> 1. feature 3 (0.954666)
> 2. **feature 6 (0.014117)**
> 3. feature 0 (0.011529)
> 4. feature 1 (0.010586)
> 5. feature 2 (0.006785)
> 6. **feature 4 (0.002204)**
> 7. feature 5 (0.000112)

In every row, feature 4 has the same value. Same is for feature 6.

Here is the code

## Random Forest

```
importances = rfclf.feature_importances_
std = np.std([tree.feature_importances_ for tree in rfclf.estimators_],
             axis=0)
indices = np.argsort(importances)[::-1]

# Print the feature ranking
print("Feature ranking:")

for f in range(x.shape[1]):
    print("%d. feature %d (%f)" % (f + 1, indices[f], importances[indices[f]]))
```

## CART

```
importances = clf.feature_importances_
std = np.std([tree.feature_importances_ for tree in rfclf.estimators_],
             axis=0)
indices = np.argsort(importances)[::-1]

# Print the feature ranking
print("Feature ranking:")

for f in range(x.shape[1]):
    print("%d. feature %d (%f)" % (f + 1, indices[f], importances[indices[f]]))
```

I would except that the importance is like:

> 6. feature 6 (0.000000)
> 7. feature 4 (0.000000)

When I just don't use that two features, my models overfit.

Comment: I think it means RF didn't find a more significant feature to "split", which probably means features with lesser importance are just noise. Did you set a depth? You should try depth=None to see if it keeps using features 4 and 6. Another thing to try would be to just keep features 2 & 3 and see if the score changes.

Comment: When I just don't use that two features, my models overfit.
@CoMartel but I will try your recommendations out

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a limit to the depth of your trees. I recommend doing a gridsearch over min_samples_leaf=[0.001, 0.1] - trying between 0.1% to 10% in each leaf.

Any kind of feature importance calculation must be done on a robust model to be meaningful.